# How to enable CURL in UNIX server?

Tags: shell-script, solaris, curl

I have to make a web service call through CURL in shell script. For this, CURL should be enabled.

Below is my server details:

```
Sun Microsystems Inc.   SunOS 5.10      Generic January 2005
```

below is a web service call through CURL:

```
curl -u graeme:abcd -i -F name=files -F filedata=@employees.csv https://app.abcxyz.com/api/settings/employees/upload/csv_external
```

- How should I enable or install CURL in my Solaris server?
- Can I use CURL in my shell script?
- Through CURL, can I post the file too?

Comment: What kind of UNIX are you running?

Comment: Depending on what system you're running on, install `curl` from repositories, download the source and compile it, use the ports system to install it, or whatever other means your unspecified distribution uses to install software.

Comment: If it's Oracle Linux then `yum install curl` if it's Solaris you'll have to use OpenCSW

Comment: Your OS is old. If on Sol11 it would be simple. I suggest to spend the $25 and buy the [Companion CD](http://unixpackages.com/packages/companion-cd) which you can use over and over again on all servers in your org and it includes many, many packages. On Sol11 you'll get it for free from Oracle's official IPS repo.

Answer (score 1):

Depends upon which unix/linux you are using, you would need to install "curl" package.

If it supports rpm, install curl rpm after downloading from any rpm repositories (e.g. http://rpmfusion.org/ ) or setup yum.

If its debian based try getting debian based package using apt-get etc.

Note: download and install only those packages which are compatible to 64/32 bit version of your operating system.